# pixel in dosbox is not aligned

Tags: assembly, dosbox

Why the pixel of my dosbox is not aligned, I do checking of the X and Y intersection to find the correct position of the pixel and in my checking I'm on the correct position of the pixel but why it always goes to the wrong position...
please help me.

see the picture with red circle for wrong pixel location

[image: wrong pixel location]

```
title marvel.asm
dosseg
.model small
.stack 0100h
.code
marvel_start:
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

        mov ax, 1003h
        int 10h

        ;bg_color
        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 70h
        mov ch, 0h
        mov cl, 0h
        mov dh, 24h
        mov dl, 79h
        int 10h


        ;dead_pool
        ;black_highlight
        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 1h
        mov cl, 9h
        mov dh, 1h
        mov dl, 14h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 2h
        mov cl, 8h
        mov dh, 2h
        mov dl, 8h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 2h
        mov cl, 15h
        mov dh, 2h
        mov dl, 15h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 3h
        mov cl, 7h
        mov dh, 3h
        mov dl, 7h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 3h
        mov cl, 16h
        mov dh, 3h
        mov dl, 16h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 4h
        mov cl, 6h
        mov dh, 8h
        mov dl, 6h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 4h
        mov cl, 17h
        mov dh, 8h
        mov dl, 17h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 9h
        mov cl, 7h
        mov dh, 9h
        mov dl, 7h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 9h
        mov cl, 17h
        mov dh, 9h
        mov dl, 18h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 9h
        mov cl, 17h
        mov dh, 9h
        mov dl, 18h
        int 10h

        ;weapon_of_dead_pool_left
        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 5h
        mov cl, 2h
        mov dh, 5h
        mov dl, 3h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 6h
        mov cl, 2h
        mov dh, 6h
        mov dl, 2h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 6h
        mov cl, 4h
        mov dh, 6h
        mov dl, 4h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 6h
        mov cl, 4h
        mov dh, 6h
        mov dl, 4h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 7h
        mov cl, 5h
        mov dh, 7h
        mov dl, 5h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 7h
        mov cl, 3h
        mov dh, 7h
        mov dl, 3h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 8h
        mov cl, 4h
        mov dh, 8h
        mov dl, 4h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 9h
        mov cl, 5h
        mov dh, 9h
        mov dl, 5h
        int 10h

        ;weapon_of_dead_pool_right
        ;pixel_not_align   
;        mov ax, 0600h
 ;       mov bh, 01h
  ;      mov ch, 4h
   ;     mov cl, 21h
    ;    mov dh, 4h
     ;   mov dl, 22h
      ;  int 10h
        ;pixel_not_align
;        mov ax, 0600h
 ;       mov bh, 01h
  ;      mov ch, 5h
   ;     mov cl, 22h
    ;    mov dh, 5h
     ;   mov dl, 22h
      ;  int 10h
        ;pixel_not_align
        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 5h
        mov cl, 20h
        mov dh, 5h
        mov dl, 20h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 6h
        mov cl, 19h
        mov dh, 6h
        mov dl, 19h
        int 10h

        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 01h
        mov ch, 7h
        mov cl, 18h
        mov dh, 7h
        mov dl, 18h
        int 10h











        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
end marvel_start
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for why you're using the scroll function (`ah=06h`) instead of the simpler set_cursor_position function (`ah=02h`)?

Comment: maybe you can add comments, what those instruction should be actually doing, because it's not obvious. For example `mov ax, 1003h` `int 10h` will set EGA card to display either 16 background colours (8+8 with intensity), or 8 base colours with blinking, but you don't set `bl` to anything, so it's not clear which mode you want to set up and why you have incomplete code ( http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-10.html ) ... etc...

Comment: my only problem is the pixel always got too far unlike the other pixel.
can you check my codes that have comment "pixel not align"?

Comment: I don't understand how you draw "pixels", and you are in text mode, so "pixels" are space characters with contrast colour, but it's not clear how you draw them through ["scroll up" BIOS service](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-6.html), and why you decided to do so, while there are another 3-8 services to draw characters on screen, some even supporting colour attributes, and you can also write directly into text-mode video ram, bypassing BIOS services completely. (i.e. I don't understand your current code, from my point of view it's completely wrong since 4th instruction - hard to help)

Comment: Oh, actually the thing you are asking about is simple to explain. You are writing coordinates in hexadecimal, but you miscalculated X coordinate, going 18h, 19h, 20h and 21h (skipping 1Ah, 1Bh, ... 1Fh coordinates). In this particular case probably use rather decimal coordinates, they are easier to read for human, and you don't set up `cx/dx` with single instruction anyway, where hexa would make writing simpler, example: `mov ch,12h` `mov cl,34h` can be merged into faster `mov cx,1234h` .. the same in decimal is: `mov ch,18` `mov cl,52` -> `mov cx,4660` (4660 = 18*256+52).

Comment: So make sure you understand the difference in number formatting, and how to convert decimal<->hexadecimal in head/on_paper, and that you understand, that writing in source code `mov ch,12h` vs `mov ch,18` is the same thing, producing the identical machine code. The number formatting is there for author convenience, sometimes it is simpler to use hexadecimal formatting (when you want to see values of separate bits and bytes just by seeing the hexa value), sometimes it is simpler to use decimal values (when binary representation is not interesting, but value is human-ish).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as this is simple typo thing (using `20h` instead of `1Ah`). Otherwise the code is showing many bad practices and unclear choices of services, so this question IMO isn't particularly useful (future wise). But your way of posting the question is actually OK, showing you use dosbox, adding working source, a bit lacking in problem description... next time add also assembler you use (probably TASM?) and it will be quite close to proper good [MCVE] question. But your asm code skills need lot more work, keep up studying+coding, you are on good [but long] path. :)

Comment: instead of copying your same lines of code over and over and over and over and over again, perhaps you think about reading that values from some kind of table or something ?

Comment: thanks for all of your comments, now I know my prof didn't teach us the correct or maybe the much better coding in assembly, i have to do a lot of research before I finish my project...